# Backwards settings in sbt (allowInsecureProtocol)

Tags: sbt

I'm trying create a global setting for publishTo. The problem I have is that our repository is only configured for http not https.

As of sbt 1.3 I need to add allowInsecureProtocol to the setting, however since this is not part of the sbt 1.2 API I cannot have a setting which is used in 1.2 and 1.3, which breaks any projects which have yet to migrate to 1.3.

Is is possible to configure this conditionally. e.g. .sbt/1.2/global.sbt and .sbt/1.3/global.sbt.

Comment: Nope, you cannot. But you can create a sbt plugin which sets up some options for your projects and have different version of this plugin in different projects. As a rule of thumb don't put into `global.sbt` things you couldn't remove later without breaking your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not recommended but I have managed to hack things with reflection.

```scala
 val hacked = try {

    classOf[MavenRepository]
      .getMethod("withAllowInsecureProtocol", classOf[Boolean])
      .invoke(repo, true.asInstanceOf[AnyRef])
      .asInstanceOf[MavenRepository]

  } catch { case _: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException => repo }
```